# multiple queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

How I can use querySet interface for two and more models?
for example:

```
assortments = get_list_or_404(Assortment, [some_list]) #this is content_types of each models
category = [ assortment.type.model_class() for assortment in assortments ]
all_goods = map(lambda cl: cl.objects.filter(has_shop=True, **kwargs).distinct(), category)
all_goods = reduce(lambda l,l1: l.extend(l1) or l, all_goods, [])
```

but now i cant use querysets methods, like order_by, for example
how else can i get list of objects from different models?

Comment: ok. and what is the best way to sorted my list by prices for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. A queryset is an ordered collection of instances of a single model type. There's no such thing as a queryset of multiple models.

Comment: +1, and it's very tightly-coupled to the `Model` concept as well!  http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/query.py#L31  Can't even manually create your own generic `QuerySet` to handle this unless you boil it down to one common model.